# ng-style background image not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I am trying to change the background image using ng-style

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/images_gameplay/trading-'+color+'-1px.png)'}">
```

When it renders its looking for local path like "`url(file:///G:/images_gameplay/trading-darkblue-1px.png);`"

Comment: I think you can't have '+' in ng-style

Comment: How should the path be?

Comment: It renders the local file path. "file:///G:/" i want the relative path of the image.

Comment: @MartelBenjamin + works here well

Comment: Problem is in your path you specified. Try to give path from parent directory i.e "app/images/" I tried this in my app like "<div ng-init="name = 'category-sprite'" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(app/public/images/' + name +'.jpg)'}">" its working for me.